# How to get all the campaigns in Ad Analytics in Linkedin Ads API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am new to working with APIs and especially with Linkedin API. 
I want to get Ad Reporting data.
I only know to get a specific campaign data.
How do I get all the campaign running for the account id?

Here is what I have run.

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=CREATIVE&dateRange.start.day=27&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.year=2019&timeGranularity=DAILY&campaigns[0]=urn:li:sponsoredCampaign:123456

I tried something like following and it didn't work.

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=CREATIVE&dateRange.start.day=27&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.year=2019&timeGranularity=DAILY&account=123456

Comment: Have you tried to pivot by ACCOUNT?

Comment: I just tried it. like following        https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=ACCOUNT&dateRange.start.day=27&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.year=2019&timeGranularity=DAILY  I get an error for missing facet. Something is missing from it.

Comment: I was able to make it work with appending accounts[0]=urn:li:sponsoredAccount:123456   at the end

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this recommendation? I think it's what you're looking for.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaigns#search-for-campaigns
>
> **Search for Campaigns**
>
> You can search for campaigns by ID, account,
> campaign group, name, type, and status fields. Search criteria can be
> chained together for increased granularity. If a search query is
> omitted, the API returns all the campaigns that the caller has access
> to.

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2?q=search&search.{searchCriteria}.values[0]={searchValue}
```